# ngx-datatable horizontal scrolling not working on mobile device

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

During my testing on mobile phone, I noticed that ngx-datatabe horizontal scrolling is not working when accessing table over the real device.

When doing testing on the Chrome development mode on mobile device layout, everything works as expected. The only random result that I had was to start scrolling from the edge of the screen and then it worked in about 10% of the cases.

```
<mat-card class="p-0" [@animate]="{value:'*',params:{y:'50px',delay:'300ms'}}">
  <mat-card-content class="p-0">
    <ngx-datatable
        #table
        class="material striped"
        [loadingIndicator]="loadingIndicator"
        [rows]="items"
        [columnMode]="'flex'"
        [headerHeight]="50"
        [footerHeight]="50"
        [limit]="page.size_"
        [scrollbarH]="true"
        [externalSorting]="true"
        [rowHeight]="'auto'"
        [sortType]="'multi'"
        (sort)="onSort($event)"
        [externalPaging]="true"
        [count]="page.count_"
        [offset]="page.page_"
        [selectionType]="'single'"
        (page)='onPage($event)'
        (select)='onSelect($event)'
        [selected]="selected">
...
```

Did anyone else had similar problem? Version used: "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "11.1.7", Angular 6.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this by using `[scrollbarH]="true"`.